# gd library is install but not working

Tags: php, installation, xampp, gd

I am using xampp gd lib is installed but it's not working

it's gives

> Fatal error: call to undefined function imagescale()

Here it is my phpinfo details:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0.35
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.9
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 7.0
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.35
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

Can anyone help me in this case

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [**`imagescale()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php) is available only on PHP version >= 5.5.0. Seems like your server is not running that. Double-check your PHP version on your `phpinfo()` again which is on the topmost leftside on your screen.